# Integers aren't open sets

Tags: real-analysis

So I am solving the following question in apostol Determine all accumulation points of the following sets in $R^1$ and decide whether the sets are open or closed (or neither).

All integers:

The set of integers doesn't contain an accumulation point of Z I will do it by contradiction suppose x $\in \mathbb{R}$ is an accumulation point so we must have all balls of radius r > 0 to have points in common with integers in particular consider B(x,x/2) we have $(B(x,x/2) - {x}) \cap \mathbb{Z} = \emptyset$, so set $\mathbb{Z}$ doesn't contain an accumulation point.

Now I want to prove that our set Z is open I proved it is closed since if we consider $\mathbb{R} - \mathbb{Z} = \bigcup_{n \in \mathbb{N}}(n, n + 1)$ is union of open sets which is open. I already see the logic of how to prove that our set Z isn't open since for every open ball we will always have points in irrational numbers but I can't seem to be able to prove it rigorously.

Comment: $\mathbb{Z}$ is closed set in $\mathbb{R}$. Since $\mathbb{Z}$ contains all accumlation points $\phi \subset \mathbb{Z}$ ($\phi$ is subset of any set)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To prove $\Bbb{Z}$ is not open, you could show that 1) $\Bbb{R} \setminus \Bbb{Z}$ is not closed or that 2) $\Bbb{Z}$ consists of isolated points.

1) 0 is an accumulation point of $\Bbb{R} \setminus \Bbb{Z}$ because it is the limit of the sequence {1/n}, but since $0 \in \Bbb{Z}$, it is not in $\Bbb{R} \setminus \Bbb{Z}$.

2) Let $a \in \Bbb{Z}$ and consider the open ball $B(a,1/2)=(a-1/2,a+1/2)$. Since $\Bbb{Z}\cap B(a,1/2)=\{a\}, a$ is an isolated point of $\Bbb{Z}$, so it is not an interior point of $\Bbb{Z}$.

The argument with the irrational numbers that you mention is another way of showing no point is interior; I think you could say that any open ball around $a \in \Bbb{Z}$ contains irrational numbers because the set of irrational numbers is dense in $\Bbb{R}$, so the ball is not fully contained in $\Bbb{Z}$.

Comment: I see I wanted to ask a question about showing it using (1) I was thinking about it but I realized we could have a set that is both open and closed so a set being closed doesn't automatically mean that it is not open correct?

Comment: I also wanted to ask how come showing that $\mathbb{Z}$ constiting of isolated points will automatically prove that is not open ??

Comment: About 1), you are correct, a set may be both closed and open. What I was using was not that, but the fact that a set is open if and only if it's complement is closed, so showing the complement is not closed proves that the set is not open.

Comment: About 2), an isolated point cannot be an interior point (because a point is isolated in a set if the set does not contain any open neighborhood of the point, and a point is interior in a set if the set contains a neighborhood of the point). The definition of open set I used was that a set is open if every one of its points is an interior point, so showing that *one* of its points is not interior proves that a set is not open.

Comment: Okay good thanks alot I understand everything perfectly now +1

Comment: You're welcome!